Problema al suscriberme a un evento
Hola buenas tardes estoy realizando un programa en javascript donde al escribir un comando en un <input> aparezca la información en un <textarea>; el problema es que al dar con el comando sub Evento 1 por ejemplo aparece que se suscribió a Evento es decir que no lo identifico bien.
Cuando uso split divido la cadena en subcadenas es decir si introduzco "sub Evento 1" se dividen en [sub],[evento],[1] por lo que al hacer dos splits como parametros en handleSubscribeCommand considero que solo se toma como una variable.
Realicé un regex para determinar que fuera la palabra Evento y aparte el número pero tal parece que solo identifica las palabra Evento sin el número.
// Constantes para definir los comandos disponbiles a utilizar
const COMMAND_ASK = "ask";
const COMMAND_SUBSCRIBE = "sub";
const COMMAND_UNSUBSCRIBE = "unsub";
const COMMAND_LIST = "list";
const COMMAND_ASK_ALGORITHM = "ask algorithm";
const CONFIRMATION_SUBSCRIBE = "Estás seguro de que quieres suscribirte a este evento?";
const CONFIRMATION_UNSUBSCRIBE = "Estás seguro de que quieres desuscribirte a este evento?";

// Algoritmos disponibles a usar
var algoritmosDisponibles = ["FCFS", "FIFO", "RR", "SJF", "SRT", "HRNN", "MLFQ"];

// Eventos disponibles a usar
var eventosDisponibles = ["Evento 1", "Evento 2", "Evento 3"];
var eventosSuscritos = [];

// Permitir la escritura de comandos en el search-input y mostrar los resultados en la terminal
var commandInput = document.getElementById("search-input");
var commandOutput = document.getElementById("command");

// Añadir Evento
commandInput.addEventListener("keydown", handleCommand);

// Manejar comando
function handleCommand(event) {
  if (event.key === "Enter") {
    const command = commandInput.value.trim();
    switch (command.split(" ")[0]) {
      case COMMAND_ASK:
        handleAskCommand();
        break;
      case COMMAND_SUBSCRIBE:
        handleSubscribeCommand(command.split(" ")[1], command.split(" ")[2]);
        break;
      case COMMAND_UNSUBSCRIBE:
        handleUnsubscribeCommand(command.split(" ")[1], command.split(" ")[2]);
        break;
      case COMMAND_LIST:
        handleListCommand();
        break;
      case COMMAND_ASK_ALGORITHM:
        handleAskAlgorithmCommand();
        break;
      default:
        handleInvalidCommand();
    }
  }
}

// Manejar comando "ask"
function handleAskCommand() {
  const resultado = "Eventos disponibles: " + eventosDisponibles.join("\n");
  commandOutput.value = resultado;
}

// Manejar comando "sub"
function handleSubscribeCommand(eventName) {
  if (eventName) {
    const fullEventName = eventName.match(/^Evento (\d)$/) ? `Evento ${eventName}` : eventName;
    if (fullEventName && !eventosDisponibles.includes(fullEventName) && !eventosSuscritos.includes(fullEventName)) {
      if (confirm(CONFIRMATION_SUBSCRIBE)) {
        eventosSuscritos.push(fullEventName);
        commandOutput.value = `Suscrito a ${fullEventName}`;
      }
    } else {
      commandOutput.value = "Nombre del Evento Inválido o ya estás suscrito a este evento";
    }
  } else {
    commandOutput.value = "Nombre del Evento Inválido";
  }
}

// Manejar comando "unsub"
function handleUnsubscribeCommand(eventName) {
  if (eventName && eventosSuscritos.includes(eventName)) {
    if (confirm(CONFIRMATION_UNSUBSCRIBE)) {
      const index = eventosSuscritos.indexOf(eventName);
      eventosSuscritos.splice(index, 1);
      commandOutput.value = `Desuscrito de ${eventName}`;
    }
  } else {
    commandOutput.value = "Nombre del Evento Inválido o no estás suscrito a este evento";
  }
}

// Manejar comando "list"
function handleListCommand() {
  const subscribedResultado = "Eventos suscritos: \n" + eventosSuscritos.join("\n");
  commandOutput.value = subscribedResultado;
}

// Manejar comando "askalgorithm"
function handleAskAlgorithmCommand() {
  const resultado = "Algoritmos Disponibles: \n" + algoritmosDisponibles.join("\n");
  commandOutput.value = resultado;
}

// Manejar comando inválido
function handleInvalidCommand() {
  commandOutput.value = "Comando Inválido. Solo se pueden usar ask, subevent_name client_name, unsub event_name, list o ask algorithm";
}


Por qué no haces como todos los lenguajes y soportas solo identificadores sin espacios. Así, tus eventos pordían ser ["Evento1", "Evento2", "Evento3"], que obtendrías de manera simple con el split. Otra alternativa es que si el elemento encontrado es "Evento", mires el siguiente elemento en búsqueda del número de evento que se quiere asociar.
